# Derivative of isotropic tensor function of a second order symmetric tensor

Tags: derivatives, tensors

I have met the wall trying to prove this identity:

$$\left[\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial\boldsymbol{\epsilon}}:\frac{\partial\ln{\mathbf{B}}}{\partial\mathbf{B}}\right]\mathbf{B} = \frac{\partial\psi}{\partial\boldsymbol{\epsilon}}$$

Here $\psi = \mu\mathrm{tr}\left(\boldsymbol{\epsilon}^2\right)+\frac{K}{2}\left[\mathrm{tr}(\boldsymbol{\epsilon})\right]^2$ such that

$$\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial\boldsymbol{\epsilon}} = 2\mu\boldsymbol{\epsilon}+K \mathrm{tr}\left(\boldsymbol{\epsilon}\right)\mathbf{1}$$

and $\boldsymbol{\epsilon} = \ln{\mathbf{V}} = \frac{1}{2}\ln{\mathbf{B}}$ is a symmetric second order tensor. The problem arises when I try to differentiate $\ln{\mathbf{B}}$ wrt. $\mathbf{B}$

If the identity is to hold, the differentiation of $\ln{\mathbf{B}}$ wrt. $\mathbf{B}$ should yield the symmetric fourth order identity tensor, $\mathbf{I}_4 = \delta_{ik}\delta_{lj}$ dotted with the inverse of $\mathbf{B}$. If that's the case we will end up with:

$$\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial\boldsymbol{\epsilon}}:\mathbf{I}_4\mathbf{B}^{-1}\mathbf{B} = \frac{\partial\psi}{\partial\boldsymbol{\epsilon}}$$

where the property $\mathbf{A}:\mathbf{I}_4 = A_ij\delta_{ik}\delta_{jl} = A_{kl} = \mathbf{A}$ was used.

Does anybody have any suggestions or pointers to help me out? I have tried using spectral decomposition -- regretfully without any luck.. Though I suspect it's the way to go.

Comment: The derivative of the matrix logarithm in general is quite ugly. The kind of formula you're looking for (somethiong like $d \ln B = dB\; B^{-1}$) holds only when $[B,dB] = 0$, so it's only going to help you if $\partial \psi/\partial \bf\epsilon$ and $B$ are simultaneously diagonalizable. Maybe something nice about $\psi$ makes this true.

Comment: Since $\partial\psi/\partial\boldsymbol{\epsilon}$ is essentially a tensor function of $\ln{\mathbf{B}}$, and that $\mathbf{B}$ is a symmetric _positive definite_ second order tensor, I guess they should be diagonalizable. Still not sure how that should help me though.. :)